# Как вернуть фокус в элемент?

Tags: jquery, javascript-events, focus

Есть такой код.
При смене фокуса проверяются данные, если они не верны, нужно вернуть фокус в поле.
При таком решении естественно все зацикливается.

```
$('#jform_propview').blur(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();            
    var value = $(this).val();
    var result = testPropview(value);

    if (result === false) {
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: а зачем делать так `result === false`? Никогда не понимал. Просто пишите так: `!result`. И избавляйтесь от этой вредной привычки.

Comment: https://github.com/index0h/php-conventions#42-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: @And, а как это ты по приведённому коду определил, что в `result` находится именно boolean?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да потому что, это видно, у него даже на скрине, что тебе адресован это утверждается `true` или `false`. Я просто сначала предположил, что это так, я был прав. Горе программисты =)  Раз уж на то пошло и нужно явно знать булев тип, то и нужно использовать `Bolean` или же `typeof`. Хотя вообще и это будет странным ибо уже говорит о том, что проблема в логике скриптов.

Comment: @And, проверка `smth === false` - стандартная проверка, если дефаултным (вместо undefined) значением должно быть true. Аналогично может быть проверка `smth === true`, если есть ещё значения, которые могут использоваться, но это встречается реже.

Comment: @Qwertiy, бред это а не стандартная проверка. Это не требуется.

Comment: @And, по коду из вопроса непонятно, может ли функция testPropview вернуть, например, null или undefined.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо тебе! благодаря таким как ты, такие слабые духом в силу болезней нервной системы не убегают с ресурса и не пытаются убивать морально тех кто их давит...

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такое вот решение.

```
$('#jform_propview').blur(function (e) { 

    var value = $(this).val();
    var result = testPropview(value);

    if (result == false) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(this).focus();
        }, 0);
        return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: Не знаю уж, где ты это ухитрился найти, но оно вообще никак работать не может.

Comment: @Qwertiy оно работает... а вот $(this).focus(); гоняет по циклу без остановки код и выдает сообщение о том что поле неверно заполнено и не дает изменить значение в поле...

Comment: Внутри таймаута this - это window. Этот код никак не может возвращать фокус на input.

Comment: @Qwertiy да возможно, этот код уже уехал отдельно и туда передается объект инпута. https://c2n.me/47ftHBS правда не знаю за счет чего он работал до этого тогда...

Comment: Вот с obj ещё может быть... Хотя мне кажется, jQuery так раньше не работал. Но точно не с this.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $(this).focus();
> ```

```
this.focus();
```